# How to prefer a retina images in srcset?

Tags: image, srcset

On the page: http://steyoyoke.com/shop/

The images appear blurry on certain screens, even though there is a retina image in each image's srcset

If you erase the first image in the `srcset` using Chrome's Inspector, the image appears less blurry.

```
<class="portfolio_img" srcset="http://files.steyoyoke.com/2017/image/jpeg/Clothing-220x160.jpg, http://files.steyoyoke.com/2017/image/jpeg/Clothing-220x160@2x.jpg 2x">
```

**Is there any way to prefer the retina image in srcset?**